# Matlab - derivation of function of variable, but no function defined

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, differentiation

Sorry for the complicated headline.

my basics idea is:
I have a function, lets say `z(t) = x(phi(t)) + y(phi(t))`

The twist where I couldn't find anything is:
suppose I want to calculate the symbolic derivation dz(t)/dt BUT without knowing neither x(t) nor y(t) specifically.

Can Matlab deliver something aloong the line

```
dz/dt=dx/d phi * dphi/dt + dy/dphi * dphi/dt
```

And if so, how do I have to program that?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? Do you have access to the Symbolic toolbox? Have you considered using a different software for this specific purpose (such as Maple, Mathematica, etc.)? Did you try `MuPAD`? Maybe [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/214902-how-can-i-define-a-sym-variable-say-t-and-sym-functions-say-q1-t-and-q2-t-such-that-i-can-create#answer_178106) could help you.

Comment: Yes, I have the the Symbolic Toolbox. And I have the latest Version of Matlab. And yes the link helps as it clarifies what I already thought.